# Explanation Needed For A Javascript Hoisting Example

Tags: javascript, hoisting

I was going through some Javascript Hoisting concepts and came across this example.

```
console.log(a)
var a=5;

function a(){
console.log('In Console')
}

console.log(a)
```

The output is

```
function a() {
 console.log('In Console');
} 

5
```

I didn't understand the different behavior for two *console.logs*

Can anyone explain?

Thanks!

Comment: Functions are always hoisted to the very top - variables are hoisted beneath them so when you call `var a=5` you replace the `a` function. You could use `a = function() {` to avoid the function hoisting itself to the very top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-evaldeclarationinstantiation)

> 7. Let declaredFunctionNames be an empty List.
> 8. Let declaredVarNames be an empty List.

Also

> 15.b.i Let bindingExists be varEnvRec.HasBinding(vn).

Which means that JS engine will hoist the functional declarations first, and while iterating through variable declarations it checks if the variable if that name already has a binding or not.

Explanation is as follows

```
// Before the following console statement function has been hoisted already and variable declaration is ignored.
console.log(a)

var a=5; // now the value of a is initialized.

//this statement has been hoisted above already
function a(){
console.log('In Console')
}

//value of a is 5 now
console.log(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

Functions declarations hoisted with it's body (by spec). So, `function a` hoisted before first `log`. Then, variable `a` is reassigned, and second `log` prints 5.

So, after hoisting you function turns to something like this:

```
var a;

a = function(){
    console.log('In Console')
}

console.log(a)
a=5;
console.log(a)
```

Comment: Where is describes about "hoisting" in spec?

Answer (score 0):

```
// at this point a is a function, variable below has not yet been assigned. 
// functions can be called from anywhere in the code file (not taking scope into account)
console.log(a)
// a is now assigned to a variable and assigned to 5, it no longer refers to the function
var a=5;

// function defined as a which can be called as a until a is reassigned
function a(){
console.log('In Console')
}

// a now refers to 5 at this point in the execution
console.log(a)
```